# Epsilon-Delta Proof of Limits?

Tags: limits, proof-writing

Does anyone know how to do this using the epsilon delta proof I am still new to the concepts and I am having trouble seeing it with actual equations instead of theoretically. It would really help me out

a) $$\lim_{x \to 0}(x+1)^4$$

b) $$\lim_{x \to -1}(x+2)^3$$

Comment: Actually one of the hardest thing for beginners about $\epsilon-\delta$ is about the adjustment of the final inequality to be $\epsilon$, so you may see that one may artificially adjust both $\epsilon/2$ inequalities before betting into the final one. In fact, that is not necessary, as long as the final inequality ends with something like $P(\epsilon)$ with $P(\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, it will work, so ending with $2\epsilon$ is fine, $\epsilon^{2}$ is fine, but $\epsilon+1$ is no good.

Comment: So, with $0<|x|<\epsilon$, one may have $|(x+1)^{4}-1|=|(x+1)^{2}+1||x^{2}+2x|\leq(1+(\epsilon+1)^{2})\epsilon(\epsilon+2)$, actually this should be considered as a correct proof, for clean version, take in particular $\epsilon<1$, then $|(x+1)^{4}-1|<15\epsilon$ will work.

Answer (score 0):

I can do part $a)$ on the friendship note...Observe that the limit $L = 1$. Thus for any $\epsilon > 0,  |f(x) - 1| = |(x+1)^4-1|= |(x+1)^2-1||(x+1)^2+1|= |x(x+2)|((x+1)^2+1)\le |x|(|x|+2)((x+1)^2+1)$. Now let $|x| < 1\implies -1 < x < 1 \implies 0 < x+1 < 2\implies 1 < (x+1)^2 + 1 < 5\implies |f(x)-1| \le 3\cdot 5|x|=15|x|$. Thus choose $ \delta = \text{min}(1,\dfrac{\epsilon}{15})$. Then if $0 < |x| < \delta \implies |f(x)-1| \le 15|x| < 15\delta \le \epsilon\implies |f(x)-1| < \epsilon$. Can you solve part $b)$ using similar idea ?